# Dichotomising vs keeping categories in regression

Tags: regression, categorical-data, binary-data

I'm doing an analysis to see if having children is associated with treatment outcome.
The *children* variable is categorical and takes values 0-7.
When I dichotomise it into 'children' and 'no children', there is no effect.

[image]

But if I keep all the levels, there is a significant association with having 3 children.

[image]

I'm not sure how to interpret it. Should I keep all the categories? Is this a real finding or a fluke? I know dichotomising is generally not a good idea but I thought it's warranted with such a variables where Yes and No are so clearcut.

For context, this is not my main research question, I'm looking at many potential risk factors and it's just one of them so I don't necessarily need to analyse it too deeply.

Comment: Why did you decide to treat number of children as categorical? Wouldn't "having exactly 3 children" be a rather strange risk factor?

Comment: @dipetkov I guess that's exactly what I'm asking, I do think it's a strange risk factor but couldn't decide if I should throw away this 'finding'. Or do you mean it should be treated as numeric? I tried that but the association was not significant.

Comment: To summarize: if you consider whether a person is a parent or not, the association is not significant; if look at the association with number of children instead (did you assume any possible relationship is linear?), it's also non significant. But if you look at having exactly 3 children, then that might be a real finding. The procedure you've described doesn't seem particularly rigorous.

Comment: Your summary is correct except that I didn't specifically check if having 3 children is a predictor. I first looked at the variable as it was (numeric) and there was nothing, so I decided to turn it into a factor in case the relationship is indeed non-linear, that's how the 3 children came up. Would very much appreciate if you could describe a more rigorous way to handle this!

Comment: This is a fun question, but it may require some discussion in the comments before we arrive at an answer. Here is another observation, based on your parameter estimates: the risk decreases as you have 1, 2 or 3 children, then increases as you have 4 or 5 children, finally decreases again with 6 or 7 children. That does not seem to make a lot of ecological sense. I can picture a U-shaped effect, but not really something that looks like a cubic. I would very much recommend including the number of children as a numeric predictor, and quite possibly its square.

Comment: You are completely right that dichotomising is frowned upon (here). But categorising an inherently numerical variable like "*number* (!) of children" is pretty much the same. It amounts to treating the relationship between $n$ and $n+1$ children as precisely the same as the relationship between *any* $n$ and $m$ children, and that does not make a whole lot of sense: the outcomes between 1 and 2 children should be more strongly related to each other than the outcomes between 1 and 7 children.

Comment: A flexible way to allow for non-linearity, if supported by the data, is to use splines. I would also make (and show) a plot of the raw data.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include your data (ideally by pasting in the output of `dput(...)` applied to your dataframe) and your model?

Comment: If there is any association, it maybe because number of children is a proxy for other life choices / circumstances. So another drawback of your analysis is that you seem to have other covariates but you are looking at the association with number of children in isolation from everything else you know about the subjects.

Comment: Also @dipetkov According to my answer there's no indication of anything meaningful going on here. I'd advise against nonlinear modelling here because doing even more based on looking at the data first will involve even more "data dredging" and p-values become even less useful after such actions. (I'd say different things if there were a clear indication that something nonlinear is in fact going on.)

Comment: @ChristianHennig: yes, your point about changing the model after looking at it invalidating p values is of course correct. To which I would answer that including the number of children as a *categorical* covariate should never have been done in the first place. I did not need to see the parameter estimates to know that this does not make ecological sense. So I would still advocate changing the model to a linear + square effect (or use splines, but I think that might be overkill here) to account for a potential U-shape, and then look again at the results.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Looking at the result I could well imagine a monotonic/linear relationship with just not enough information at >3 children to see it. Chances are this wouldn't turn out significant on these data let alone involving a squared term, but after having seen the given results already everything is "lost" anyway.

Comment: @ChristianHennig: we can certainly agree to disagree here. I would just like to state for the record (and the OP) that my position is not quite as strict as yours: if I see the results of an analysis that I can argue is problematic *without relying on the results*, I would definitely recommend running a correct analysis over interpreting the results of an inappropriate analysis "by the book". YMMV.

Comment: @StephanKolassa unfortunately, the output of dput() is massive, not sure how to make it more concise. To you other point, does it still make sense to interpret the observations even if they are not significant? (referring to risk changes as the number of children goes up)

Comment: @dipetkov, you're absolutely correct, there are other covariates. I have hundreds of variables and run univariate analyses first to select step wise the ones I'll keep for the multivariate model. Is it a wrong way to do it?

Comment: I would not start interpreting insignificant effects - they might be just random noise, especially since you presumably have very few data points with 6 or 7 children. (And because I still believe an analysis with categorical data makes no sense.)

Comment: Yes, I think the kind of univariate selection you describe has drawbacks. It is also a separate question from the one you've posted. You could consider writing a new question that the describes your data, the ultimate purpose of your analysis, your proposed approach and ask for feedback about that.

Comment: Forgive me if this is too much of an elementary question, but from your post, I read your research question as being, "Is having children associated with the outcome?", which to me, seems like you are only interested in the dichotomised yes/no response, anyway.

Comment: @Trypanosoma that's a good clarification. I'm interested in finding all possible predictors of treatment outcome and children is just one of the possible predictors. There's no established question whether it's yes/no or number of children hence checking both.

Comment: I would treat no. of children (n) as a continuous variable. You would expect a priopri that the more children you've got, the less difference would another one make. This assumption could be taken into account using sqrt(n) or log(n+1) as the predictor. Looking at your results, I guess you would get a significant slope out of this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you test every number of children separately, you're running seven tests. According to Bonferroni, for making sure that you have a probability of smaller than 5% to find a significant result if in fact nothing is going on, you've got to run every single test at level 0.05/7. This is smaller than the p-value for 3 children. From this point of view nothing significant is going on in either situation. You may well keep all categories, but this doesn't give you a meaningful significance. (Obviously you could find that p-value suspicious and collect much more data to see whether it becomes even more significant, but it may not be worth the hassle.)

Added later: There was some discussion about whether it is wrong to treat the number of children as categorical, actually being a number, and what to do instead.

Generally I agree with the view that it makes sense to use the numerical meaning of the data. However this will usually involve assumptions about the functional form of the relationship. An important principle is that all available subject-matter knowledge should be used *before* actually analysing the data, as making modelling decisions based on the data will often produce selection bias effects and runs counter to theory behind some standard methods such as the significance tests for the coefficients.

So that first step *before seeing the data* should be to ask what kind of functional relationship could make sense here. The easiest assumed relationship would be linearity, but linearity may not be realistic, particularly because there may be a much bigger difference between 0 and any number of children than between two nonzero numbers of children (of course I can't tell without knowing the exact background). Also the relationship may be non-monotonic.

An additional problem is the question what can be identified from the data at what precision. Standard errors for 5, 6, 7 (maybe even 4) children suggest that there is not much data for these and whatever can be said will be very imprecise. In fact one could know this already from the plain numbers of observations falling into these categories (taking those into account will hardly bias later analyses as they don't imply information about the regression relationship).

This means that there may not be enough information to nail down confidently any relationship more complex (i.e., requiring more parameters) than a linear one, and making assumptions that require only a low number of parameters to be estimated is certainly desirable. This also means that treating the larger numbers of children as autonomous categories doesn't give useful information either. The standard errors of about 19 suggest that there is hardly any power to detect anything; for sure shown results cannot even exclude the possibility that there is a monotonic or even linear relationship (or none at all), even though the latter may not be realistic.

If relationships don't follow simple functional forms, in fact aggregation of categories can be a sensible choice; depending on the background comparing zero with existing children may be justifiable, and in general even something like "zero", "one or two", "more than two" can work better than either using all numbers as separate categories (particularly with very thin numbers on some categories) or assuming linearity or a more complex functional form. As said before, optimally such decisions should be made before seeing the data (or at least the regression relationship); however looking at the data may reveal a *striking* specific deviation from an initial assumption/decision, in which case model selection bias is probably less bad than sticking to an inappropriate initial decision at any cost.

From the numbers I currently see, I suspect however that clear evidence for any influence of this variable whatsoever cannot be found in the given data, and I'd be very skeptical if any of the ideas above applied at this time point would lead to a just about significant p-value, which in that case may well be explained by model selection bias.

Note also, as discussed elsewhere, that looking at p-values often isn't a very good way of doing variable selection.

Comment: This is all completely correct, but to be honest, I can't bring myself to upvoting it, because while it answers the question, it does not answer the question the OP *should* be asking as long as [they categorize a numerical predictor in a rather obviously ecologically invalid way](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/604000/dichotomising-vs-keeping-categories-in-regression#comment1120566_604000)...

Comment: @StephanKolassa so just to make sure I understand you correctly. Number of children is a kind of variable that should've never been treated as categorical. But is it warranted, upon looking at a numeric one and getting no significant results, to dichotomise it? Only for this case, when it seems ecologically plausible that children/no children are very different from each other.

Comment: @StephanKolassa From the comments (which may be too many at this point), it seems that this is an XY question as the OP is doing univariate feature selection to choose predictors to include in the multivariate model they want to develop.

Comment: @olke: it depends. If you want to do inferential significance testing, then *any* kind of model selection after seeing the data invalidates the theory on which p values are predicated - you do need to specify your model before doing any fitting. (Hence the discussion between Christian and me.) If you are just doing exploratory analysis, or building  predictive model, pretty much anything goes. There is a strong temptation to overfit, so you really need to include ecological understanding, per my comments - and then you need to validate on new data.

Comment: @StephanKolassa I have added to my answer; hope that this is to your liking. ;-)

Comment: Thank you, it is, +1!

Answer (score 7):

This is a great example of why it is so difficult to 'hypothesize after the results are known' and why we should make analysis plans before we start, even for observational data.  Every analysis we try now will just reflect something we've already seen, and we could probably find an analysis to give whatever answer we want.

IMO we can't say whether or not having children affects your outcome based on this data. Certainly your dataset is not inconsistent with 'no effect' so this is probably how you should explain it as that's how we normally think about statistical significance.  Particularly if this also comes from a set of secondary outcomes that you are exploring.  We also can't rule out a small effect.

From a programming point of view for an 'honest' quantification of your results you might try using `emmeans` to get the base vs all other group contrasts, and use whatever p-value and confidence interval correction is recommended for this kind of comparison.  Or just report your initial model of 'number of kids' as a numeric, if this was supported by your theory and is what you tried initially.

Whether or not it makes sense to analyse the number of children in categories like this is up to you.  Social factors might make 3 kids qualitatively different from 2, Its down to your population and your theory.

Statistical arguments aside you could also consider the Bradford Hill criteria to check if you believe a result is real or meaningful.

Finally, if you don't need have an opinion about what this data means then you don't need to overthink it.  Just show your readers your model and your results and let them decide.  A graph like this might be instructive:

[image]

Comment: Nice graph! ...

Answer (score 4):

Why not run an ANOVA and see whether adding all the levels improves overall fit? If it does then you can worry about which level is driving it.